# R: Replace a data frame in a list with a new data frame

Tags: r

For example, I have three data frames a1, a2, a3 in one list c

```
a1 <- data.frame(x=c(1,2), y=c(2,3))
a2 <- data.frame(x=c(3,4), y=c(4,5))
a3 <- data.frame(x=c(5,6), y=c(6,7))
c <- list(a1, a2, a3)
```

Now I have a new data frame b1. I want the a1 in c to be replaced by b1.

```
b1 <- data.frame(x=c(7,8,9), y=c(8,9,10))
```

I tried to use `c[1] <- b1`, which does not work.
`c <- list(b1, a2, a3)` will do what I want, but is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double, rather than single brackets.

```
a1 <- data.frame(x=c(1,2), y=c(2,3))
a2 <- data.frame(x=c(3,4), y=c(4,5))
a3 <- data.frame(x=c(5,6), y=c(6,7))
c  <- list(a1, a2, a3)  
b1 <- data.frame(x=c(7,8,9), y=c(8,9,10))

c[[1]] <- b1
c
```

> ```
> [[1]]
>   x  y
> 1 7  8
> 2 8  9
> 3 9 10
>
> [[2]]
>   x y
> 1 3 4
> 2 4 5
>
> [[3]]
>   x y
> 1 5 6
> 2 6 7
> ```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/in-r-what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-notations-for-accessing-the) gives an explanation of bracket usage.